# How do I pass product title to a link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I can get the product title with
$string = $product->get_title();
$product_title = urlencode($string); //to get rid of spaces

But how to I add that $string to the middle of a url to create
http://example.com/product/$product_title/#review

I am trying to use it here (function.php) in this code modified from Display blank(0) star ratings in the Woocommerce single product pages

```
add_shortcode ( 'show_product_ratings_count', 'add_count_to_reviews_tab_item', 98 );

function add_count_to_reviews_tab_item( $title ) {
    global $product;

    $rating_count = $product->get_rating_count();

    if ( $rating_count >= 0 ) {
        $title = $product->get_title();
        $review_count = $product->get_review_count();
        $average      = $product->get_average_rating();
        $count_html   = '<div class="count-rating">' . array_sum($product->get_rating_counts()) . '</div>';
        ?>
        <div class="woocommerce-product-rating-single">

            <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
            <a href="#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">
                (<?php printf( _n( '%s customer review', '%s customer reviews', $review_count, 'woocommerce' ), '<span class="count">' . esc_html( $review_count ) . '</span>' ); 
            ?>)</a><?php endif ?>
            
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

To get the "(# Customer Reviews)" text to link to http://example.com/product/$product_title/#review in my product archive.

[image]

UPDATE

urlencode doesn't work because it adds underscores, and the permalink structure for the slug uses hyphens. So now I have:

```
global $product
$product_slug = $product->get_slug();
$url_to_review = $product_slug . "/#reviews"; //or #tab-reviews, to append the review anchor
<a href= "/product/<?php echo $url_to_review; ?>";
```

This code links to the product page and opens the reviews tab, but it does not stay on the anchor and instead jumps to the bottom of the product page.

How do I get it to stay.

Comment: You are looking for how to concat string ?

Comment: Where is the code where you want to add, the product title… note that it should be better to include the product slug in the url to have a clean url…

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, I modified the question with more detail.